# Why won't my Monthcalendar accept today's date?

Tags: c#, .net, events, calendar

This question might sound very vague but I do not know how to phrase it in a better fashion.
I've been working on a month calendar that checks if the 2 selected dates are correct. There is 1 calender that uses to following code to figure out who called the event (The startdate textbox or enddate textbox)

```
 MaskedTextBox b = (MaskedTextBox)sender;
        currentSelectedDateBox = b.Name;
```

The startdate must be sooner than the enddate, both startdate and enddate can't be a date that already has a reservation(it shows a reservation by making the date bold), and the selected period can not have a reservation in it.
 This is all working fine, although I have one problem: When I open the calendar and click on today, it closes, meaning the user has selected a date, although no date shows up and when I try to print the selected date: it won't print anything. If I select a different date, though, it will print that date, meaning that all dates can be selected except today.

If I click on a different day and then select today, it will work. This is really weird and I'm stuck.

Here's my code:

```
private void monthCalendar_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {

        ErrorStartDateLabel.Visible = false;
        ErrorEndDateLabel.Visible = false;
        startdateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        enddateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        string day = monthCalendar.SelectionStart.Day.ToString();
        string month = monthCalendar.SelectionStart.Month.ToString();
        if (day.Length == 1) //part of the stringbuilder
        {
            day = "0" + day;
        }

        if (month.Length == 1) //part of the stringbuilder
        {
            month = "0" + month;
        }

        string date = day + "-" + month + "-" + monthCalendar.SelectionStart.Year.ToString(); //Date selected
        if (startdateTextbox.Name == currentSelectedDateBox) //If the StartDate Calendar has been selected
        {
            startdateTextbox.Text = date;
            startdate = monthCalendar.SelectionStart.Date;
        }
        else if (enddateTextbox.Name == currentSelectedDateBox)//If the EndDate Calendar has been selected
        {
            enddateTextbox.Text = date;
            enddate = monthCalendar.SelectionStart.Date;
            secondDateChecked = true;
        }
        if (secondDateChecked) //if the enddate textbox has data
        {
            if (enddate < startdate) //if enddate is smaller than the startdate
            {
                enddateTextbox.Text = "";
                ErrorEndDateLabel.Text = "Uw gekozen huurperiode klopt niet!";
                ErrorEndDateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                enddateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                ErrorEndDateLabel.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        if (carHasReservation == true) //If there is a reservation
        {
            foreach (var bolddate in bolddates)      //loop through all bolded dates
            {
                if (startdate == bolddate || enddate == bolddate)//if the startdate OR enddate is a bolded date
                {
                    if (startdate == bolddate)
                    {
                        startdateTextbox.Text = "";
                        ErrorStartDateLabel.Text = "Deze startdatum is al gereserveerd!"; 
                        ErrorStartDateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        ErrorStartDateLabel.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enddateTextbox.Text = "";
                        ErrorEndDateLabel.Text = "Deze einddatum is al gereserveerd!";
                        ErrorEndDateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        ErrorEndDateLabel.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                if (startdate <= enddate)
                {
                    TimeSpan tisp = enddate - startdate;
                    int dateDiffer = tisp.Days;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dateDiffer; i++) //Count the amount of days between the startdate and the enddate. For every day, check if one of those days is a bolded(reservation) date
                    {
                        if (startdate.AddDays(i) == bolddate)
                        {
                            reservationCollision = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //No reservation, do nothing!
        }

        if (reservationCollision) //if there is a boldeddate between the selected dates
        {
            ErrorStartDateLabel.Text = "Tijdens uw geselecteerde periode";
            ErrorEndDateLabel.Text = " is er al een reservering geplaatst!";
            ErrorStartDateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            ErrorEndDateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            startdateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            enddateLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            ErrorStartDateLabel.Visible = true;
            ErrorEndDateLabel.Visible = true;
            enddateTextbox.Text = "";
            reservationCollision = false;
        }

    }
```

My explanation and code might be a bit vague, I'm sorry for that. I thought it would be better to add more information than necessary instead of giving a bad explanation of my problem and code.

Comment: I think what is happening is that the default date is today, and you selected today, so it didn't change. Try binding to the DateSelected event also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eris. It would make sense! I don't know what you mean with the DateSelected event, can you provide some more information?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.dateselected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx